# If an array is an object, why can't I return an array from an angular factory function?

Tags: angularjs, factory

I know you can return an object, so why not an array if it is an object?

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Sure you can just tell it to the `$resource` using `{ isArray: true }`, for example:

```
angular.module('test').factory('Test', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/test', {}, {
        query: { isArray: true }
    });
  }
]);
```